# Compute $\int_{-1}^{1}x\sqrt{x}\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{x})dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was trying to make an IBP problem for an integration bee.
I came up with the simple arctan integral with the square roots just for an easy round.
However, WolframAlpha challenged me a suggestion, which was adding the bounds -1 to 1.
I was so confused because I thought it was undefined, divergent, or complex. But it turns out the answer is real and defined.

My attempt was performing integration by parts in which I got the indefinite answer:
$$ \left [ \frac{2}{5}x^{\frac{5}{2}}\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{x})-\frac{x^2}{10}+\frac{1}{5}x-\frac{1}{5}\ln|x+1| \right ]_{-1}^{1}$$
The hardest part was inputting the bounds as I am unaware of some weird odd values.
$$\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{5}\ln(2)-\left(\frac{2}{5}i\tan^{-1}(i)-\frac{3}{2}-\ln(0)\right)$$
Not only that, the answer is $\frac{2}{5}+\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{\ln(2)}{5}$.

Did I do anything wrong? How do I come to this exact answer???

Comment: You at least need $\tanh x = -\mathrm{i} \tan(\mathrm{i}x)$ (... to be used on the half of the integral on $[-1,0]$).

Comment: $i$ is a logarithmic singularity of arctangent (because $i$ is a $\sim x^{-1}$ singularity of the derivative, $(1+x^2)^{-1}$). This means the logarithms cancel in some way as you take the limit symmetrically, i.e. $\lim_{x\to-1^+}\frac{1}{5}x^{\frac{5}{2}} \tan^{-1}\sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{5}\log(x+1)$ exists but it is not obvious what this limit should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first split the integration interval into two.
$$
\int_{-1}^1 x \sqrt{x} \tan ^{-1} \sqrt{x} d x 
=  \underbrace{\int_0^1 x \sqrt{x} \tan ^{-1} \sqrt{x} d x}_{\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{5} \ln (2)} +  \underbrace{ \int_{-1}^0 x \sqrt{x} \tan ^{-1} \sqrt{x} d x}_{J} 
$$
For the integral $J$, we let $x\mapsto -x$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
J & =-\int_0^1 x(\sqrt{x} i) \tan ^{-1}(i \sqrt{x}) d x \\
& =\int_0^1 x \sqrt{x} \operatorname{arctanh}(\sqrt{x}) d x \\
& =2 \int_0^1 x^4 \operatorname{arctanh} x d x
\end{aligned}
$$
By the [expansion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power%20series%20of%20arctanh%20x) of arctanh $x$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
J& =2 \int_0^1 x^4 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2 n+1}}{2 n+1} d x \\
& =2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n+1} \int_0^1 x^{2 n+5} d x \\
& =2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n+1)(2 n+6)} \\
& =\frac{1}{5} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{n+3}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{5}\left(\psi(3)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\\&= \frac{1}{5}\left((\frac32-\gamma)-(-\gamma-2\ln 2) \right)\\&=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{3}{2}+2\ln 2\right)
\end{aligned}$$

where $\psi(.)$ is the [Digamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Hence $$I= \frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{5} \ln (2)+\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{3}{2}+\ln 4\right)= \frac{2}{5}+\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{\ln(2)}{5} $$
In general,
$$
\boxed{\int_{-1}^1 x^k \sqrt{x} \tan ^{-1}(\sqrt{x}) d x=\frac{1}{2(2 k+3)}\left[(\pi+1-2 \ln 2)+2\left(\psi(k+2)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\right]}
$$

Comment: YOOO, the part where u=-x converts trig stuff into hyperbolics was very cool!! Thank you for that!!!

Comment: Glad to know that it is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I do not claim to know how WolframAlpha works behind the scenes. This is merely an attempt to walk through its reasoning for the integral over the negative part of $[-1,1]$.

WA chooses branches of the [square root](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify+sqrt%28x%29+if+-1%3Cx%3C0) and [logarithm](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=alternate+forms+arctan%28x%29) such that

$$\sqrt x = \begin{cases} \sqrt x & x\ge0 \\ i \sqrt{-x} & x<0 \end{cases} \\
\arctan x = \frac1{2i} \log \left\lvert\frac{1+ix}{1-ix}\right\rvert + \frac12 \arg\left(\frac{1+ix}{1-ix}\right)$$

so that when $x\in(-1,0)$, it works on the expression

$$\begin{align*}
x\sqrt x \arctan \sqrt x &= i x \sqrt{-x} \left[\frac1{2i} \log \left\lvert\frac{1-\sqrt{-x}}{1+\sqrt{-x}}\right\rvert + \frac12 \arg\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{-x}}{1+\sqrt{-x}}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac12 x \sqrt{-x} \log \frac{1-\sqrt{-x}}{1+\sqrt{-x}}
\end{align*}$$

Substitute $x\to-x$ to get a more tractable integrand,

$$\int_{-1}^0 x \sqrt x \arctan \sqrt x \, dx = -\frac12 \int_0^1 x \sqrt x \log \frac{1-\sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x} = \int_0^1 x \sqrt x \operatorname{artanh} \sqrt x \, dx$$

WA confirms these have the same value. [LHS](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x*sqrt%28x%29*artanh%28sqrt%28x%29%29+from+x%3D0+to+1)/[RHS](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x*sqrt%28x%29*arctan%28sqrt%28x%29%29+from+x%3D-1+to+0)

How WA actually evaluates either definite integral is hard to pinpoint. Working on the RHS, one approach would be to replace $x\to x^2$ and exploit Taylor series:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^0 x\sqrt x \arctan \sqrt x \, dx &= \int_0^1 x\sqrt x \operatorname{artanh}\sqrt x \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 2x^4 \operatorname{artanh} x \, dx \\
&= \sum_{n\ge0} \frac2{2n+1} \int_0^1 x^{2n+5} \, dx \\
&= \sum_{n\ge0} \frac2{(2n+1)(2n+6)} \\
&= \frac25 \sum_{n\ge0} \left(\frac1{2n+1} - \frac1{2n+6}\right) \\
&= \frac25 \left[\frac12 + \frac14 + \sum_{n\ge0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\right] \\
&= \frac3{10} + \frac25 \log2
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Should  the (-) in  the last answer  $\frac3{10} - \frac25 \log2$ be (+)?

Comment: Right, thanks. I mixed up the sums starting with $n=1$ vs. $n=0$.

Comment: Wonderful solution!